# TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'encoding') in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm attempting to load a simple grass block from Minecraft and it is showing an error that reads `TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'encoding')`  from the GLTFLoader line 2893 which only says `texture.encoding = encoding;`. I'm not using textures so I'm not sure why it is showing this error. The following code loads the grass block.

```
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load(
        'https://cdn.glitch.global/c7ffc3e9-df32-4837-b046-23be12a0896a/minecraft_grass_block.glb?v=1664906819996',
        
        function ( gltf ) {

            scene.add( gltf.scene );

            gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
            var grass = gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
            gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
            gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
            gltf.asset; // Object

            console.log(grass)

        },
        // called while loading is progressing
        function ( xhr ) {

            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {
            console.log( error );

        }
    );
```

Here is the full error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'encoding')
    at GLTFLoader.js:2893:23
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

```
THREE.GLTFLoader: Couldn't load texture blob:null/23946df4-f704-42bc-a59d-bd78afa6a4fc
```

Comment: It mentions setting encoding under Textures - https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader - not sure if you tried that.

Comment: I actually didn't notice that. Although I's still having issues mushing my code and theirs together. I'll keep trying with that and if you have any suggestions than that would be great!

Comment: Also there is an error that reads "THREE.GLTFLoader: Couldn't load texture blob:null/23946df4-f704-42bc-a59d-bd78afa6a4fc" if that helps

Comment: As it can't load the texture, the texture variable is null, hence it can't set encoding on null. Fix the texture loading issue and you'll probably fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one texture can't be loaded. It might be missing. Review the network tab looking for 404 errors, you might find the missing image there.